# Kentico 11 Page Type Field display name

Tags: kentico

Using Kentico 11
I have a content only page type with some custom fields. The page types are children of a container page type.
2 questions:
1. How does Kentico determine the field that will be used as the display name (red arrow) once the type is saved?
2. Can I make the display name a composite of two fields (the green arrows)?
Would be a shame to make the user enter the same info multiple times (once for the display name, once for each field that makes up the display).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can define that name field on the actual page type in the Fields tab directly under the list of field names. There is a dropdown box you will select a field name from. The field has to be a text field and be required to show in that dropdown.
2. You cannot use 2 fields for that name UNLESS you write a custom event handler to update the information